# Creating a new object from a function in python

Tags: python, object

```
class SlidePuzzle(object):

    def __init__(self, state = None):
        if state == None: state = [[1,2,3],[4,'N',5],[6,7,8]]
        self.puzzle_state = list(state)

    def isValidMove(self, move):
        x,y = self.getBlank()

        if move == 'up':
            return y != 0
        elif move == 'down':
            return y != 2
        elif move == 'left':
            return x != 0
        elif move == 'right':
            return x != 2
        else:
            print "Invalid Move"
            return 0
    def getValidMoves(self):
        validMoves = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']

        if not self.isValidMove('down'):
            validMoves.remove('down')
        if not self.isValidMove('up'):
            validMoves.remove('up')
        if not self.isValidMove('right'):
            validMoves.remove('right')
        if not self.isValidMove('left'):
            validMoves.remove('left')

        return validMoves

    def generateChildren(self):
        return [SlidePuzzle(self.puzzle_state).move(m) for m in self.getValidMoves()]
```

If I run these commands:

```
- p = SlidePuzzle()
- print p
- p.move('up')
- print p
- print p.generateChildren()
- print p
```

This is the output. I have not included all of my source but as you can see the the move function works as needed.  What I dont understand is why the generateChildren function not only doesnt seem to be creating any new Slide Puzzle Objects but it also messes with the puzzle state of the calling object.

```
- [1, 2, 3]
- [4, 'N', 5]
- [6, 7, 8]

- [1, 'N', 3]
- [4, 2, 5]
- [6, 7, 8]

- [None, None, None]

- [1, 2, 3]
- [4, 'N', 5]
- [6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

`generateChildren` returns a list of return values from `SlidePuzzle.move()`, not a list of `SlidePuzzle` objects. You don't show `move`, but I suspect it returns None.

Comment: You don't need to "suspect".  it *does* return `None` (since you see the result in the output list).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That was a dumb mistake after alot of banging my head against the wall.  I fixed generate children to look like this\n  `code`  def generateChildren(self):
        validMoves = self.getValidMoves()
        children = [SlidePuzzle(self.puzzle_state[:]) for m in validMoves]
        
        for i in range(len(children)):
            children[i].move(validMoves[i])
        return children  `code` \n but the move command still doesnt appear to be affecting the newly created slide puzzle objects. They are simply in the default state

Comment: Please add the definition of `move()` to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Lists are passed by "reference", so you have to copy the list at first, otherwise your new Puzzle will operate on the same list:

```
def generateChildren(self):
    return [SlidePuzzle(self.puzzle_state[:]).move(m) for m in self.getValidMoves()]
```

Note the `[:]` which copies the list.

Furthermore `.move` returns `None`, that's why it ends up beeing `None`.

Comment: `SlidePuzzle.__init__` makes the copy of the given list.

Comment: Does this explain why it currently returns `None`?